# Which temple is being referred to in Acts 2:46?

Tags: new-testament, acts, temple

In the book of Acts, a certain temple seems to be being referred to in chapter 2 verse 46:

> Every day they continued to meet together in the temple courts.

Which temple is this?

Comment: There was only one temple, in Jerusalem, the one [Jesus visited and predicated would be destroyed](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024:1-2&version=NLT). So I'm a bit puzzled by this question: what else could it have been?

Comment: PS Welcome (should have started with that) and please check out [this starter page](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1927/newcomers-be-patient-you-will-get-there-if-you-follow-our-direction-keep-tryi?cb=1)

Comment: JFB says this meant: observing the hours of Jewish worship (9AM and 3PM.) There was only one Temple for Judaism, in Jerusalem (the other was on Mt. Gerizim used by Samaritans.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temple in Jerusalem was destroyed in AD 70.

Acts 2 records how Holy Spirit was poured down on the Day of Pentecost (v 1-4). And then Peter addressed the crowd who were amazed and confused what was going on. Most of them were Jews who came to Jerusalem for the Pentecost festival (v 5). Following Peter's sermon, 3000 were baptized that day (v 41). From verse 42, the writer recorded the activities of the first believers. They devoted to the apostles’ teaching (v 42), they shared everything (v 44) and they met together in the temple courts everyday (v 46).

Acts 2 is no doubt before the destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem. Hence, it refers to the Temple in Jerusalem and none other.

**What were they doing in the Temple courts?** Meeting together and preaching about Jesus Christ as we see in the immediate next chapter, Acts 3, where Peter and John healed a lame man who was begging at the temple gate.

> *Acts 3:11 (NIV)* While the man held on to Peter and John, all the people were astonished and came running to them in the place called
>   **Solomon’s Colonnade**.

The believers  used to meet together in [Solomon’s Colonnade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon%27s_Porch), which was  on the eastern side of the temple.

> *Acts 5:12 (NIV)* The apostles performed many signs and wonders among the people. And all the believers used to meet together in **Solomon’s
>   Colonnade**

You can see the picture of how the temple at that time looked like [here in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple).

Answer (score 0):

In Acts 1:8, Jesus tells the disciples that they will be witnesses for him 1) in Jerusalem, and 2) in all Judea and Samaria, and 3) to the ends of the earth.

> But you will receive power when the Holy Spirit has come upon you, and you will be my witnesses **in Jerusalem** and **in all Judea and Samaria**, and **to the end of the earth**.”   Acts 1:8 ESV

Acts 2-7 has the disciples 1) in Jerusalem, so the temple in Jerusalem is what they are referring to.  After the persecution begins with the stoning of Stephen in Acts 7, the disciples are scattered across 2 Judea and Samaria.

> And Saul approved of his execution.  And there arose on that day a great persecution against the church in Jerusalem, and they were all scattered throughout the **regions of Judea and Samaria**, except the apostles.  Acts 8:1 ESV

Answer (score 0):

It is this one modelled here:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, Jerusalem has one big old honking Temple.  When someone is DC says, "the Washington Monument" for example, you know they are talking about the big one in the center of town, and not some random little statue there.  This would be in contrast to many Asisan cities where there are lots of Temples.

The book of Acts clearly calls out that the disciples were in Jerusalem, and Acts 3:11 points out they were running through Solomon's Collonade, ensuring that in fact yes, it was "the" [Temple in Jerusalem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_in_Jerusalem).